# VS breaking code execution without breakpoint or error

Tags: multi-device-hybrid-apps

Trying a simple test of a cordova app targeting android.

Visual studio breaks execution at the end of each js file (no breakpoints are set)
e.g. at:

```
}(this));
```

There is an earlier warning which may not be related:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. File: ripple.js, Line: 50, Column:
>   26565

Clicking continue continues execution to the end of the next file - presumably as each JS file is loaded.

Has anyone experience this and know how to prevent it breaking execution at the end of each js file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on VS 2015 Preview and VS 2013. So eventually found out that it is Windows 8.1.
The solution is to go to the network settings in Windows. On Proxy disable "Automatically detect settings".

Comment: After I had removed the "Automatically detect settings" on Proxy, I also removed the Ripple Extension from Chrome and in Visual Studio - Clear Cache Cordova, I also Clean the Build in VS and restart VS.
Does this help?

Comment: I also see Google released a security update for Chrome 23/1 2015, so if the others I have mentioned do not help, I would think the problem could be here!

https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/current-activity/2015/01/23/Google-Releases-Security-Updates-Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I don't get the warning so the warning is most likely not related. I tested the solution of PKL, but it didn't work for me.

It worked fine before, but since last Friday (23.01.), this started to happen every time I reload the page in the ripple emulator. The only thing that changed on Friday is an update to Chrome. I don't know if this could be the problem.